libclang finds the wrong clang version on ubuntu 22.04
I want to use ClangSharpPInvokeGenerator to generate some bindings, but it always returns

Unhandled exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid
libClang version. Returned string 'Ubuntu clang version
14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1' does not contain 'version 18.1'

The wierd thing is: this error is ALWAYS shown regardless whether I installed clang or not!
Note that Ubuntu 22.04 does not have clang-18 in its official reopsitory, so I installed clang-18(and link clang to it) from llvm.org.
So I want to solve this problem, and want to know: Where does it find the wrong libclang version? Does Ubuntu 22.04 installed a version of libclang WITHOUT clang itself somewhere?
